# vectorized way of checking element existence

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor a of floats a, a corresponding pytorch tensor of ints b of the same size as a. I have another tensor of ints c of variable length. I need to multiply the position of a by two if the corresponding element in b has appeared in c.

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
b = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1, 3])
c = torch.tensor([1, 2])

# Convert 'c' to a set for faster membership testing
c_set = set(c.tolist())

# Use vectorized operations to update 'a'
update_mask = torch.tensor([idx in c_set for idx in b], dtype=torch.bool)
a[update_mask] *= 2
```

This is the fastest way I can think of. Is there a more optimal way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

***[NB.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene)** As per your description, I don't believe your current attempt works. This is what your `update_mask` looks like: `tensor([False, False, False, False])`.*

Regardless, you can use broadcasting to create a 2D mask where each element of 'b' is compared to each element of 'c' in a vectorized manner, which may perform better than creating a set of the elements of `c`:

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
>>> b = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1, 3])
>>> c = torch.tensor([1, 2])
>>> update_mask = (b.unsqueeze(1) == c).any(dim=1)
>>> update_mask
tensor([False,  True,  True, False])
>>> a[update_mask] *= 2
>>> a
tensor([1., 4., 6., 4.])
```